# I just want the query to return only modules in a gridview which are associated with eg FirstName

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I only need the query to return modules where Student Firstname is equal to say "ceaer"

Thank you, I earlier posted one of these but obviously I might have misled you guys. Its only the modules I want returned from the query below.

```
List<Student> arrList = new List<Student>();
    //   ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();
        arrList.Add(
            new Student
            {
                FirstName = "Svetlana",
                LastName = "Omelchenko",
                Password = "hh",
                modules = new string[] { "001", "002", "003", "004" }
            });
        arrList.Add(
            new Student
            {
                FirstName = "Claire",
                LastName = "O’Donnell",
                Password = "hh",
                modules = new string[] { "001", "002", "003", "004" }
            });
        arrList.Add(
            new Student
            {
                FirstName = "Sven",
                LastName = "Mortensen",
                Password = "hh",
                modules = new string[] { "001", "002", "003", "004" }
            });
        arrList.Add(
            new Student
            {
                FirstName = "Cesar",
                LastName = "Garcia",
                Password = "hh",
                modules = new string[] { "HH", "KK", "LL", "OO" }
            });


        var result = from student in arrList
                     where student.FirstName == "Cesar"
                     select student.modules;
        GridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();


        At the moment, this is what the query returns

        Length | Long Length | Rank | IsReadOnly | IsFixedSize.,........
          4           4          1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linq query in your code is returning an `IEnumerable<string[]>`, because you are selecting a collection of the `modules` property, which is an `string[]`

If you want to display the modules array itself (and just the modules for ONE student), you can change the query logic a bit:

```
var student = (from student in arrList
               where student.FirstName == "Cesar"
               select student).FirstOrDefault();

if(student != null)
    GridView1.DataSource = student.modules;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @alexphi. That definately helped :). If you please don't mind with a bit more help. Would you know how I would update the array? something like (Update student FirstName, LastName, modules[] where for example FirstName = "Cesar". The biggest problem here for me is updating the modules string array. Otherwise thank you so much

Comment: To update the modules array you can simply set the new values to the selected `student` object after the query, like `student.modules = new [] {"001", "005" };`